# Should I limit inrush current of this MOSFET buck regulator?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, buck, powermosfet, digital-control

I am building a digitally controlled constant current switching power supply. This circuit will deliver no more than 105 Watts at around 20V from an AC-DC DIN rail SMPS of 250W.

You can see and operate the circuit in [falstad](https://tinyurl.com/2ye4prcl)

Here is a screenshot of it at maximum power delivery when duty cycle is at 100%:

[image: a digitally controlled MOSFET buck regulator in falstad circuit]

The worst case scenario is if the MOSFET gate signal starts at 100% duty cycle. The capacitor will start charging rapidly and current through the inductor and MOSFET will increase continuously until the capacitor is fully charged. Since this is a digitally controlled system, I want to make sure that the components are safe even if the software bugs out.

The approach I took is downsizing the capacitor to 4.7uF which in simulation gives a good amount of ripple at the output for the application and a peak charge current of 6A. I will be using a 7A inductor as when the regulator is at full power it will supply 5 Amps. The inductor is the bottleneck setting the maximum current through the regulator to 7A max.

I see that the appropriate solution is an NTC thermistor and found the EPCOS B57237S0259M000 to be the appropriate candidate.

My question is: Given that the regulator will be powered by an AC-DC SMPS, can I rely on the SMPS' overcurrent protection?

And my guess is: No. Because the SMPS overcurrent protection might trigger at a current way over my components' rated spec (7 Amps, the inductor's rating).

Comment: What are you specifically trying to protect? Your circuit, or the downstream circuitry (not pictured)? If you are worried about the inductor, they can certainly tolerate the over current condition until the DC supply overcurrent kicks in. A bigger issue will be at those currents, the inductor saturates. What inductor and simulation tool do you use? Cause if you do simulations with ideal parts, you won't see this effect, and your peak current may be far worse than you think.

Comment: Why are you using a zener diode where you'd normally see a Schottky--did you just get the symbols confused, or do you have some good reason for the zener there? And if this is meant to provide 5 A, I would give some thought to using a synchronous rectifier to reduce losses, too.

Comment: There is a better way: monitor inductor current, and adjust PWM based on that. You can intrinsically limit peak or average current, where it's being drawn, and then regulate output voltage. Current-mode control furthermore allows splitting the output filter pole pair. This should be solved in analog hardware, not MCU -- ensuring it's done correctly in software, each and every cycle, is far from trivial.

Comment: Have a look at LT3763 to solve this in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

1. for 1st question, you need to look at the datasheet of AC/DC SPMS, if the rating current is significantly larger than 5A, the OCP point may be 1.2x rating current or higher. Thus you can't rely on it.
2. The best way to limit the inrush current is to add the soft-start feature, you can start up your buck regulators by increasing duty cycle slowly from 0, don't use 100% duty cycle to regulate the output current, 100% duty clcle means a LC filter from VIN to OUT.